# Error Illuminate Database Eloquent Not Found

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

In the Controller when i tried to call a function from a model it Through Exception

```
Symfony \ Component \ Debug \ Exception \ FatalErrorException (E_ERROR)

Class 'Illuminate\Database\Eloquent' not found
```

the controller is simple and i used to create name space to manage sub directories controllers and model

```
<?php
namespace Manage ;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\View;
use Illuminate\Routing\Controller;
class BaseController extends Controller {

    /**
     * Setup the layout used by the controller.
     *
     * @return void
     */
                    protected $layout = 'manage.layouts.master';
    protected function setupLayout()
    {
        if ( ! is_null($this->layout))
        {
            $this->layout = View::make($this->layout)->with(Dashboard::all());
        }
    }

}
```

and model

```
<?php
namespace Manage ;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent;
class Dashboard extends Eloquent{
    protected $table = 'admin_dashboard_sidebar';
    //put your code here
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't you be extending `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model`?

Comment: This worked for me `composer install`

Answer (score 13):

The class is Model:

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model as Eloquent;
```

or just

```
use Eloquent;
```

This last one is an alias to the class you can find in your `app/config/app.php`.

Comment: When i used use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model as Eloquent; it through 
ErrorException (E_UNKNOWN) Illegal offset type
and when i used use Eloquent; only the past error still remain

Comment: So you have to check if your Laravel is correctly installed. Check if `vendor/laravel/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php` file exists.

Comment: I don't have this in config/app.php

Answer (score 0):

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Dashboard extends Model{
}
```

Comment: Code dumps do not make for good answers. You should explain *how* and *why* this solves their problem. I recommend reading, "[How do I write a good answer?"](//stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). This can help future users learn and eventually apply that knowledge to their own code. You are also likely to have positive feedback/upvotes from users, when the code is explained.